# Using SkyDrive to share file. Why I don't see shared files on my computer when syncing?

Tags: onedrive

My Mom wants to share some of her files with me. I can see them if I log in to SkyDrive. I don't see them on my SkyDrive folder on my computer though.

How can I arrange it so that all shared files are also on my computer, Dropbox style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure skydrive doesn't let you sync shared folders be sync'd to the other person's local drive ... Mesh did it and you can get Google Drive to do it